# How to optimize the pagination query?

Tags: performance, php, php5, pagination, cakephp

This is completely optimization question, I have a pagination query like this:

```
$this->paginate    = array(
        'fields'    =>  array(
                        'DISTINCT Contact.contact_id',
                        'Contact.first_name',
                        'Contact.last_name',
                        'Contact.email',
                        'Contact.created',
                        'ContactGroup.name',
                      ),  
        'conditions' => array(
                        $this->conditions,
                        'ContactsContactGroup.contact_group_id'=>$viewList,                        
                        isset($keywordQuery)?$keywordQuery:"",
                      ),      
        'limit'      => 5,
         'group'     => array('Contact.contact_id')
                      );
$data = $this->paginate('ContactsContactGroup');
$data = $this->paginate('ContactsContactGroup');
```

This query is called in every if and else statement, I have four conditions of `if` and `else`, and in all conditions the above piece of code is written.

I want to optimize, and avoid the big line of code in every condition. How can I optimize it? Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: you can half the cost of that code by calling paginate only once =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could wrap it all in a function:

```
function pagination($this,$viewList,$keywordQuery)
{
    $this->paginate    = array(
        'fields'    =>  array(
                        'DISTINCT Contact.contact_id',
                        'Contact.first_name',
                        'Contact.last_name',
                        'Contact.email',
                        'Contact.created',
                        'ContactGroup.name',
                      ),  
        'conditions' => array(
                        $this->conditions,
                        'ContactsContactGroup.contact_group_id'=>$viewList,                        
                        isset($keywordQuery)?$keywordQuery:"",
                      ),      
        'limit'      => 5,
         'group'     => array('Contact.contact_id')
                      );

   return $this->paginate('ContactsContactGroup');

}

if(something())
{
    //something
    $data=pagination($this,$viewList,$keywordQuery);
}
else
{
    //other
    $data=pagination($that,$viewList,$keywordQuery);
}
```

etc..

Comment: I'm sorry, but really, what sort of code review comes up with an answer that includes `global`?

Comment: just a quick way to clean up his duplicate code. either that, or they can just delete it all, start over.

Comment: I get you though. @usii, maybe make the function return $data;